# Regarding twitter search API request limit

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

On the twitter Rate Limiting page(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting) it says

"*Unauthenticated calls are permitted 150 requests per hour. Unauthenticated calls are measured against the public facing IP of the server or device making the request.*"

1. Is that the measurement based on enduser IP address or the server IP(ip of http:xxxx.com) ?
2. Is there a way to increase the limit may be through some paid service of Twitter ?

Regards,
Navin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Server IP
2. No. But you should use authenticated calls (oAuth) - you get 350 requests per hour. Each authenticated user of your app has 350 calls you can use, IP ignored.

Comment: is there any paid service offered by twitter on API?

Comment: yes - **firehose** - but i doubt they will even respond to you if you are smaller than google or bing